# Is it possible to use a for loop to display values using buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello here is my code at the moment. I would like to be able to display "you have selected" and then the name of the player that you pressed the draft button with however when pressing the button then it says you have selected "undefined". Would anyone be able to help thank you very much

```css
var players=["Patrick Mahomes",
"Tyreek Hill",
"Travis Kelce",
"Chris Jones",
"Tom Brady"];
len=players.length;
for (var i=1;
i < len;
i++) {
  document.getElementById("draft").innerHTML+=players[i]+"<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"draft()\">Draft</button><br>"
}

function draft() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+="You have selected"+players[i]+"<br>";
  players.splice(players[i]);
}
```

```html
<p id="draft"></p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You may want to review the arguments to the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function. The first one is never a string.

Comment: Currently this code does nothing. Are you sure you have given us the entire code?

Comment: value of `i` is referring a undefined value , you have updated your value of i , i.e it's 6 currently and hence you are getting undefined

Comment: @cs1349459 hello yes this is the javascript code but I have a html page where this is run but I just wanted to know how to implement the javascript before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you don't specify the index when calling `draft`. You have to call it with the current index. I modified your code for it to work.
It should be easy to understand.
I also changed your `var` to `let` as it is better practice in javascript

```
<script>
    let players = ["Patrick Mahomes", "Tyreek Hill", "Travis Kelce", "Chris Jones", "Tom Brady"];
    let len = players.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        document.getElementById("draft").innerHTML += players[i] + "<button type='button' onclick='draft("+i+")'>Draft</button><br>"
    }

    function draft(player) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "You have selected " + players[player] + "<br>";
        players.splice(players[player]);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's so helpful. Yes you are right I definitely should have used let!

Comment: @joefarrell62 glad i could help! you can upvote and mark it as the accepted answer so that people know you fixed your issue

Comment: hello I'm so sorry to bother you but I have encountered another problem in the code. Would you be able to take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can pass the player name as arg for `draft()`

```
for (var i=1;i<len;i++) {
document.getElementById("draft").innerHTML+=players[i]+"<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"draft('"+players[i]+"')\">Draft</button><br>"
}
function draft(player){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+="You have selected "+player+"<br>";
    players.splice(players[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass `i`

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head> 
    <title> 
        Draft
    </title> 
</head> 
  
<body>
<p id="draft"></p>
<script>
var players=["Patrick Mahomes","Tyreek Hill","Travis Kelce","Chris Jones","Tom Brady"];
len=players.length;
for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
document.getElementById("draft").innerHTML+=players[i]+"<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"draft("+i+")\">Draft</button><br>"
}
// use different variable name for function parameter as var has scope for i here
function draft(k){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+="You have selected"+players[k]+"<br>";
    players.splice(players[k]);
}
    
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I didn't test but should work. I don't know why you are using `players.splice(players[i]);` but if you want to remove the element from players use

```
players.splice(k, 1);
```

See more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Syntax

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the index to your method draft so you can use it to display the right cell from your array:

```js
var players = ["Patrick Mahomes", "Tyreek Hill", "Travis Kelce", "Chris Jones", "Tom Brady"];

for (var i = 1; i < players.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector("#draft").innerHTML += players[i] + "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"draft("+i+")\">Draft</button><br>"
}

function draft(index) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "You have selected " + players[index] + "<br>";

}
```

```html
<p id="draft"></p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you made a typo at declaring the "len" var.

try to use "var len = players.length" or use a comma after the players var declaration.

Comment: The lack of `var` makes the variable a global variable. Potentially problematic in the long run, but not causing any problems in this particular code.